# We're found in vans, in bags, on bikes - we're found in books, in maps, online

Tags: riddle, word

> We're found in vans, in bags, on bikes,
>   Most everywhere that people dwell.
>   Dogs may hate us, but we bring
>   Important tidings, good or bad.
>
> We're found in books, in maps, online,
>   Most everywhere that info dwells.
>   China may hate us, but we're here:
>   Even in this riddle, you know.

What are we?

Comment: The answer to this riddle will be a hint for [Who are these two sisters?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/61740/5373)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I'm guessing the answer is:

> **Letters**?

We're found in vans, in bags, on bikes,

> Postal vans, postmen carry bags and ride bikes, and all of these have letters

Most everywhere that people dwell.

> And postal services are present in most populated areas

Dogs may hate us, but we bring

> Dogs chasing postmen is a long-running trope

Important tidings, good or bad.

> Letters carry news (e.g. in the past, news of a child being born, or a death)

We're found in books, in maps, online,

> Letters of the alphabet

Most everywhere that info dwells.

> A lot of information is written down with letters (most, because some information is pictorial)

China may hate us, but we're here:

> Chinese writing uses logograms, which are pictorial representations of words (similar to Egyptian hieroglyphics); these are not letters
>
>   Edit - **@Apep** pointed out in the comments that this probably refers to [China banning the letter 'N'](https://www.cnn.com/2018/03/01/asia/china-letter-ban-trnd/index.html), which does fit the riddle much better.

Even in this riddle, you know.

> Letters make up this riddle

Comment: Well, that was fast. Good job! (Too easy?)

Comment: Thank you, @Randal'Thor . For me it was lines 3-4 that gave an opening, and then the rest came together. Before I feel too proud, I should remind myself I only solved a hint to an actual puzzle, one that has me stumped! :-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor My initial thought was "words" or "newspapers", so already pretty close.

Answer (score 6):

> Postman, I would say for the first block

We're found in vans, in bags, on bikes,

Most everywhere that people dwell.

Dogs may hate us, but we bring

> Obvious until here

Important tidings, good or bad.

> Can be good like a letter from your grandma or some bad like a payment reminder

We're found in books, in maps, online,

> **books:** e.g. phone book
>  
>  **maps:** on city maps/guides the post office is normally marked and there you can find postman´s
>  **online:** you can track your package/ your postman online

Most everywhere that info dwells.

> 

China may hate us, but we're here:

> I thought first about drones because China wants to be innovative... But then I found some articles about an ongoing problem with post man´s stealing export packages. Mostly because the packages are nearly never tracked.

Even in this riddle, you know.

Comment: You're very close! The correct answer is something related to what you said, which also fits the second verse.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I was anyway to slow :) But nice and not too hard

Answer (score 3):

The riddle was answered but I still want to post my thoughts on this.
The answer (could be):

> **Chains?**

We're found in vans

> Tire **chains** for vans or **chain** of command in vanguard

In bags

> Ladies' purse often includes decorative **chain**

On bikes

> Well, this one is obvious

Most everywhere that people dwell

> Might sound inaccurate, but most of mechanical engineering's projects include **chains**

Dogs may hate us

> **Chain** leash

But we bring important tidings, good or bad

> Tryed to figure this out and the only solution that came up was **chain** letters?

We're found in books

> As pictures perhaps? It doesn't specify they're found in *every* book

In maps

> There is whole section in topology referring to **chain** maps

Online

> A lot of pictures of **chains** around the Internet

Most everywhere that info dwells

> Could be a **chain** (as sequence) of letters perhaps?..

China may hate us, but we're here:
Even in this riddle, you know.

> For a second I thought the reason China hates it because China is an anagramm for **chain** and that would explain the last line, but it sounds inaccurate.

Comment: You mean you still wanted to post your *chain* of thoughts?

Comment: @Krumia Aha, good one :)

Answer (score 2):

Working backwards from the question that this questions is a hint for, this seems to fit most of it, at least:

> Keys

We're found in vans, in bags, on bikes,

> car keys, keys in purses, keys to bike locks

Most everywhere that people dwell.

> house keys

Dogs may hate us, but we bring
Important tidings, good or bad.

> ???

We're found in books, in maps,

> The key on a map or diagram or in a technical book is a list of the symbols or abbreviations used and their meanings

online, Most everywhere that info dwells.

> Encryption Keys

China may hate us, but we're here:

> In 2015, China passed a National Security Law, which included a provision to give police the authority to demand companies let them bypass encryption

Even in this riddle, you know.

> All riddles have keys to their understanding.

Comment: Good answer, which actually fits most of the clues - but the correct answer has already been posted.

Comment: @Randal'Thor So, why has it not been selected as the "Correct Answer?" Is there more to it or something?

Comment: I always wait a while to accept answers. Don't read too much into it.

Comment: @Randal'Thor (Case in point why that practice maybe isn't the best practice. People generally look for the checkmark to know if a puzzle has been solved, rather than reading every comment on every answer to find if one is noted as being correct.)